# codeigniter - this->db->get() returns empty result

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem regarding codeigniters db->get(). I have functioning sql query, when i pass it to db "manually", i get result, but when i use codeigniter, i get empty result. Almost same query but with like instead of where works.

The SQL is:

```
SELECT se.Id, se.Name, se.Alias, sy.Name as System, os.Name as Os, ac.Name as Access, se.Description
FROM cdl_server se
INNER JOIN cdl_system sy on sy.Id = se.System
INNER JOIN cdl_os os on os.Id = se.Os
INNER JOIN cdl_access ac on ac.Id = se.Access
WHERE se.Id = 1
```

The code looks like this:

```
    $this->db->select(
            'se.Id, se.Name, se.Alias, ' . 
            'sy.Name as System, os.Name as Os, ac.Name as Access, ' . 
            'se.Description', 
            FALSE);
    $this->db->from('cdl_server se');
    $this->db->join('cdl_system sy', 'sy.Id = se.System' ,'inner', FALSE);
    $this->db->join('cdl_os os', 'os.Id = se.Os' ,'inner', FALSE);
    $this->db->join('cdl_access ac', 'ac.Id = se.Access' ,'inner', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('se.Id', $id, FALSE);
    $this->db->get();
```

edit:
I use it like:
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

When i var_dump the sql query before it is sent to the database, i get this:

```
string(264) "SELECT se.Id, se.Name, se.Alias, sy.Name as System, os.Name as Os, ac.Name as Access, se.Description FROM cdl_server se INNER JOIN cdl_system sy ON sy.Id = se.System INNER JOIN cdl_os os ON os.Id = se.Os INNER JOIN cdl_access ac ON ac.Id = se.Access WHERE se.Id =1"
```

But result is always empty, even though when i copy the above and try asking db directly, i get result i need.

Does anyone know what could be causing it?

Comment: `$this->db->join` doesn't accept a fourth parameter. Did you try `$this->db->get()->result()`?

Comment: Thank you very much, that works - but i wonder why does this work and `$query = $this->db->get(); return $query->result()` did not. Thanks again!

Comment: You need to use the `db` library to generate a result. `$query` is just a simple string. It doesn't have functions such as `result()`.

Comment: this worked for me untill now, thats why im puzzled.

Comment: if you're using `$q = $this->db->get(); return $q->result();` and still getting no results then your SQL statement clearly isn't defined properly.

Comment: Didn't see the query usage in your post. There is no difference between my and your way. Please echo `$this->db->last_query()` after you run the query and see whether the query is identical to the one you run manually.

Comment: gorgelative: funny thing - when i just rewrite it as ->get()->result(), it works, changed nothing more :); Yan: It seems like it is the same. I suppose there was some little thing i didnt notice...

Comment: if you're calling the `$this->db->*` functions within the model and using `return $query->result()` it should work if rows were returned.

Answer (score 4):

If u want to get result you must use row() or result() function.

```
$this->db->get()->result();
```